# iAd dismissed and the remaining is a BLACK SCREEN

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iad, interstitial

I was trying to integrate iAd interstitial in my iPhone App. The ad is showing correctly. But when I click on the 'ad close button', the ad dismissed and the remaining is a **BLACK SCREEN**. How do I get rid of this issue? I am loading the view from xib. ARC is enabled in project. My code is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self cycleInterstitial]; // Preparing interstitial
}

-(void)cycleInterstitial{
    interstitial.delegate = nil;

    interstitial = [[ADInterstitialAd alloc] init];
    interstitial.delegate = self;
}

- (void)presentInterstitial
{
    [interstitial presentInView:self.view];
}

- (void)interstitialAdDidUnload:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd
{
    [self cycleInterstitial];
}

- (void)interstitialAd:(ADInterstitialAd *)interstitialAd didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [self cycleInterstitial]; 
}
```

And the ad is called on a button click, as:

```
- (IBAction)showAdButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self presentInterstitial]; // Presenting interstitial 
}
```

Help me please. 
Thanks in advance.